# Release upgrade to 14 failed with a Python exception

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, do-release-upgrade

So I attempted to upgrade by running

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

as it specifies in my login prompt. It runs for about a minute before crashing with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'AptCdrom' object has no attribute 'restore_backup'
```

Can I assume this is a bug and that I won't be able to upgrade from the command line?

Is there any workaround?

**Edit**: This is a headless server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an old postgresql package that had somehow been blacklisted from removal. Since the upgrade required this package to be uninstalled, but couldn't due to the blacklist, it failed, but this true error was hidden in the logs and only this Python traceback was immediately visible.

Manually removing the package then re-running `sudo do-release-upgrade` fixed the error.

```
cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log|less
...
Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'
```

Answer (score -1):

Cited from [Release Notes - Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or Ubuntu 13.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10)

> ### Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or Ubuntu 13.10
>
> #### To upgrade on a desktop system:
>
> Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `update-manager` into the command box.
>       Update Manager should open up and tell you:
>
> ```
> `New distribution release '14.04 LTS' is available.`
> ```
>
> Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.
>
> #### To upgrade on a server system:
>
> Install the `update-manager-core` package if it is not already installed.
>
> Launch the upgrade tool with the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
>   Follow the on-screen instructions.
>
> Note that the server upgrade will use GNU screen and automatically
>   re-attach in case of dropped connection problems.
>
> *Offline upgrade options via alternate CDs are no longer offered for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Please ensure you have network
>   connectivity to one of the official mirrors or to a locally accessible
>   mirror and follow the instructions above.*

Another way to launch Update Manager to upgrade your 12.04 LTS is:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> & good luck!

Comment: What? This has nothing to do with my question. I'm trying to upgrade my release to 14.04, not a normal package upgrade. Please delete this answer or I will downvote it.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. you're right, I remember same my situation, I will edit. wait please, mate.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But it still doesn't explain why I'm getting the error on my server. Note, it's not a desktop.

Comment: Do you installed `update-manager-core` ?

Comment: please add to your question output from `uname -a`

Comment: Yes. `Linux localhost 3.2.0-67-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 17:46:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`